# Where/How to override/customize '@media (min-width' for 'col-sm-*/col-md-*'?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I see in bootstrap.css this code:

```css
@media(min-width: 576px) {
.col-sm {
-ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
max-width: 100%;
}
.....
.col-sm-2 {
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
max-width: 16.666667%;
}
```

It works for screen 576px but I need to customaize it, 640px for ex.

_variables.scss can't help me becouse there are not some variables for it.
it is question. I hope it is possable to resolve without bulk duplicating code

Comment: You can define your own put it in a separate css file and link it as the last file in the header

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, I suppose that is the single solution

Comment: @ZimSystem, If for desired result need to change the necessary media in bootstrap.css then it needs to override the css

Comment: @ZimSystem, using SASS